# How can I change ImageButton size programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

I'm generating `ImageButtons` programmatically and I'm not able to change the size of the items using `XML`. So, I would like to do it programmatically too.

How can I do that?

My code :

```
    String[] separated = result.split("%");

    ImageButton [] txt =new ImageButton[20];

    for(int i=0;i<txt.length;i++)
    {
      String getname = separated[i];
      txt[i]=new ImageButton(hphotos.this);
      Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load("http://www.mywebsite.com/" + getname).into(txt[i]);

      txt[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      scroll.addView(txt[i]);
```

Comment: To the constructor of LayoutParams you should pass the size (in pixels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
yourView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width,height));
```

?